# Get a nodeset of all local-names with xpath

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

With XPath 1.0, Instead of

```
<xsl:for-each select="*">
  <xsl:variable name="varName" select="local-name()" />
  <!-- Do stuff with $varName -->
</xsl:for-each>
```

I really want to do something like

```
<xsl:for-each select="*/local-name()">
  <!-- Do stuff with . ('.' as in the current value) -->
</xsl:for-each>
```

or

```
<xsl:for-each select="local-name(*)">
  <!-- Do stuff with . ('.' as in the current value) -->
</xsl:for-each>
```

Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A node set contains nodes. It doesn't contain names. Therefore your question contains the contradiction that proves it can't be done.

The XPath 2.0 data model makes it perfectly possible to manage a collection of names as a value. But XPath 1.0 only allows node-sets, or singleton strings, booleans, and numbers.

Comment: Thanks, didn't knew names != nodes, I thought of the name as just another attribute, but I guess that's not the case. Allright then, is it possible to convert strings to a node-set? (If this should be a new question, just say the word)

Comment: Mr Happy, with `<xsl:for-each select="*/local-name()">` in XSLT 2.0 you would process a sequence of strings (with element names) so `.` inside the `for-each` would be an atomic string value. But that is not possible with XSLT 1.0. I am not sure what you are asking with "is it possible to convert strings to a node-set", how does that relate to your current question?

Comment: @Martin Honnen, well I was thinking there might be some `ConvertToNode()` function that I could use to convert the sequence of strings to a sequence of Nodes, so that I could still solve my problem... But now that I think of it, that would imply that there would exist a hypothetical function `ConvertToNode` wich would have a sequence of strings as a parameter, wich doesn't exist in XPath 1.0 in the first place. Kinda like a catch-22, so not possible. I'll have to find another way then. Thanks for your time.

Comment: I think something is missing from this. In all those `xsl:for-each`, the issue it's not only XPath 1.0 doesn't allow sequence of atomic values as it does XPath 2.0 (although it's in the requeriments for this task): other issue is that it also doesn't allow iterations over atomic values. Do note that even allowing iteration over sequence of atomic values, XSLT 2.0 doesn't allow **matching** atomic values. Something that was added to [XSLT 3.0](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt-21/#patterns): *patterns can match any kind of item: atomic values and function items as well as nodes*