# XPath 1.0 trace ONLY element names at top nodes along path

Tags: select, xpath, smalltalk, pharo

I edited this for clarity with a much clearer example.

interesting XPath problem I have not found an answer for.

**"I would just like to trace the path from the top of the tree to a leaf without including any of the sub-branches at any node...just the node along the way without its contents...just its element name."**

given:

|tree doc|
tree := '

```
<bookstore>

<book category="COOKING">
  <title lang="en">Everyday Italian</title>
  <author>Giada De Laurentiis</author>
  <year>2005</year>
  <price>30.00</price>
</book>

<book category="CHILDREN">
  <title lang="en">Harry Potter</title>
  <author>J K. Rowling</author>
  <year>2005</year>
  <price>29.99</price>
</book>

<book category="WEB">
  <title lang="en">XQuery Kick Start</title>
  <author>James McGovern</author>
  <author>Per Bothner</author>
  <author>Kurt Cagle</author>
  <author>James Linn</author>
  <author>Vaidyanathan Nagarajan</author>
  <year>2003</year>
  <price>49.99</price>
</book>

<book category="WEB">
  <title lang="en">Learning XML</title>
  <author>Erik T. Ray</author>
  <year>2003</year>
  <price>39.95</price>
</book>

</bookstore>'.

doc := (XMLDOMParser on: tree) parseDocument.
doc explore.
```

each ancestor going up the tree in reverse document order is giving me all of its contents, I just want its QName .

The intent is for didactic purposes in documentation I am writing for it.

Say I want the ancestors of  `<author>Erik T. Ray</author>`, I just want to see `<bookstore><book><author>`.

What I end up with is The bookstore node and its children, the book node and its children and the author node and its child.

These are the correct nodes, but it is not the output I am looking for.

The intent is didactic, I would like to show that localName of the ancestor nodes without any other clutter

Thank you for your time

Comment: Should the `j` node be nested in the `w` node in this example, or are they truly meant to be siblings?

Comment: they are siblings

Answer (score 1):

For all nodes that have children:

`//*[*]`

```
In [4]: root.xpath('//*[*]')
Out[4]: 
[<Element I at 0x10bd40d00>,
 <Element w at 0x10bdb4e40>,
 <Element j at 0x10bca5f40>]
```

For all nodes with children that are not below a specific node in the document:

`//*[*][not(./preceding::<node>) and not(./<node>)]`

```
In [13]: root.xpath('//*[*][not(./preceding::ould) and not(./ould)]')
Out[13]: [<Element I at 0x10bd40d00>]

In [14]: root.xpath('//*[*][not(./preceding::ust) and not(./ust)]')
Out[14]: [<Element I at 0x10bd40d00>, <Element w at 0x10bdb4e40>]
```

However, a 1.0 XPath cannot return a set of strings, such as the local names: [Get a nodeset of all local-names with xpath](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4968770/get-a-nodeset-of-all-local-names-with-xpath)

Comment: Thank you. I will check it out in the morning.  The verbal explanations tied to the examples below where very helpful. I will be adding them to my working notes.

Comment: self xpath:'//*[*]'.   works perfectly, it selects all nodes with children.

Comment: I ran your example as is, but I continue to get the <ould> and <ust> nodes displaying. I am wondering if it is just an artefact of the engines we are using.

Comment: regardless, posting this question was worth it just for the "select all nodes with children" shortcut. thank you for your time